# Rails action params[:user] not provided how return error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am working on a project where I want ensure that if request does not have user params it should send error, so I used following method in controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_params

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end

  def check_params
    render json: { error: 'No user params provided' }, status: 401 unless params[:user]
  end
end
```

It is working fine but I have to put on each individual controller, is there way I can add it in Application for all controllers! as only `params[:user]` changing, so if I have `params[:company]` I have to add another method in CompaniesController with params[:company] which is not really dry. I am surprise when we use params.require(:user) why it gives errors instead return validation error.

Comment: If parameters names and error message are different in different controllers - simpler to have own `check_params` in controller with different parameters.  `check_params` in different controller aren't same it will not violate DRY, because methods will change for different reasons.

Comment: Yes but may be we can reduce it less code, as it is doing same functionality just changing one symbole `:user`

Comment: Why do you need to check this manually? When you use StrongParams (as you do) and you call `params.require(:user)` and there isn't such a key in the params then an `ActionController::ParameterMissing` exception will be raised which should already cover your usecase.

Comment: @spickermann I want not show that exception but a json error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look like you want to rescue from `ActionController::ParameterMissing` with a custom error message. The Rails way to do that is the [`rescue_from`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) method.

Add the following to your controller:

```
rescue_from 'ActionController::ParameterMissing' do |exception|
  render json: { error: 'No user params provided' }, status: 401
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of creating this whole method you can do just check before where your action is checking params[:user] and reject on single line like following

```
@user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]) if params[:user]
```

Now it won't search for your params[:user]

Answer (score 0):

You can move common logic into a method in the base class, then derived classes can  pass own "changeable" variables to it or ignore a method

```
class ApplicationController
  def check_params(name, error_message)
    render json: { error: error_message }, status: 400 if params[name].nil?
  end
end
```

Usage

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action -> { check_params(:user, "User is missing") }
end
```